# Django admin DateTimeField auto timezone offset

Tags: python, django, datetime, timezone, django-admin

In my settings, I've got all the timezone related stuff turned on:

- `USE_I18N = True`
- `USE_L10N = True`
- `USE_TZ = True`

Inside the admin interface, I get a note under the field:

- Note: You are 8 hours behind server time.

This is great, but it'd be much nicer if the known offset was applied to the field automatically.  Its difficult for users to calculate a DateTimeField offset in their head.

Is there a simple way to accomplish applying the user's timezone offset to the field automatically?

Comment: What an option `TIME_ZONE` is set for? Try to set it to your timezone.

Comment: TIME_ZONE='UTC', which does work, but thats not really the question.  I'm trying to figure out if the admin widgets can automatically adjust the users time zone into the servers time zone.  It would have to be something that lives inside the on save method?

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/timezones/) out? I have the same options set (USE_L10N = True;
USE_I18N = True; TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'; USE_TZ = True) and it works perfectly in django-admin (my local timezone is UTC+0500). What is your server timezone? Does it differ from your local timezone?

Comment: Did you get a solution for this?

Comment: Nope, I don't work on that project anymore though.